# send value from textarea

Tags: javascript

hello i have the following script : http://jsfiddle.net/EFjcA/

i would like my function :

```
var saveEdit = function(event2){
    var btn = event2.target,
        li  = btn.parentNode,
        p   = li.getElementsByClassName('paratext')[0],
        te  = p.parentNode;

    te.style.display="none";
    p.appendChild(te.value);
    p.style.display="block";
    btn.innerText = "Edit";
    btn.onclick = makeAreaEditable;
};
```

..to save the value from inside the textarea and display it after the button Ok is pressed.

Comment: @PaulHarbuz http://jsfiddle.net/XgxcE/ try it out

Comment: well it doesn't display the text after the Ok button is pressed... what did you changed? the problem is i think this line : p.appendChild(te.value);

Comment: @PaulHarbuz after you click ok button the style set to the text as display:none; that is why it is not visible

Comment: i need the textarea do be display none after the ok is pressed but i need the text inside sent to <p> and be displayd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the line

```
p.appendChild(te.value);
```

into

```
p.innerText = te.value;
li.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you have done is correct. But this one would resolve your issue.